# Flexible Tree Structures

Tags: java

Which is the best flexible tree structure to implement the Huffman Coding Problem and either the AVL or Splay Tree problem? Below is what I created so far as a general structure, but I am not sure if I could extend the tree class as a base class to properly implement the problems mentioned above.

```
class TreeNode< T extends Comparable< T > > 
{
  // Data members
  TreeNode<T> leftNode; // left node  
  T data; // node value
  TreeNode<T> rightNode; // right node

// constructor initializes data and makes this a leaf node
public TreeNode( T nodeData )
{ 
  data = nodeData;              
  leftNode = rightNode = null; // node has no children
} // end TreeNode constructor

// locate insertion point and insert new node; ignore duplicate values
public void insert( T insertValue )
{
// insert in left subtree
  if ( insertValue.compareTo( data ) < 0 ) 
{
 // insert new TreeNode
 if ( leftNode == null )
    leftNode = new TreeNode< T >( insertValue );
 else // continue traversing left subtree recursively
    leftNode.insert( insertValue ); 
} // end if
// insert in right subtree
else if ( insertValue.compareTo( data ) > 0 ) 
{
 // insert new TreeNode
 if ( rightNode == null )
    rightNode = new TreeNode< T >( insertValue );
 else // continue traversing right subtree recursively
    rightNode.insert( insertValue ); 
    } // end else if
  } // end method insert
}
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about your problem. Also what do you mean by **extend the tree class as a base class**? Could you be bit more elaborate?

Comment: @Blip Essentially, I will need to create a tree based class structure to perform searches on. This specific structure will need to address both the Huffman Coding and AVL Tree problems when the class will be implemented. I hope this helps clarify the situation.